# Option and null in Scala

Tags: scala

If I have the following function:

```
def getOrNull[T >: Null](f: => T): T = {
    try { f } catch { case _: NullPointerException => null }
}
```

And I want to use it with `Option` like so:

```
val r = Option(getOrNull(someString.split("/")(0)))
```

I get:

```
Error:(25, 19) Option.type does not take parameters
```

What is going on, and how can I overcome this?

Comment: 1) On 2.12.5 this compiles and runs successfully. 2) Are you aware of `util.Try.toOption`  ? 3) `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is not subtype of `NullPointerException`, so this whole construction wouldn't help much against strings without `/`-separator.

Comment: As Andrey has pointed out, you are looking for `Try.toOption`

Comment: people! What am I supposed to do with eight upvotes on my comment? If you agree, then vote to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin One may usefully ask what build tool produced the error, but one may assume that the error is not made-up. It's very easy to reproduce. It's up to the OP to update with more info if necessary, but I bet many folks write a sample Option class or use a command line parser with its own Option class, and see such an error.

Comment: @som-snytt If the OP redefined the `Option` object or imported `Option` from a cli-parser, then it would render the first seven (out of nine) lines of the question irrelevant, and the remaining lines would read like *"**My** `Option.type` does not take parameters, what's going on?"*, to which there is really no good answer, except *"Because you defined it to not take any parameters"*. Of course, one can always redefine all names. One can even force the compiler not to import `scala` and `Predef`, and then define arbitrary crazy things. But how is it useful for the rest of the world then?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin In the empty package, I see the error `nooption.scala:13: error: Option.type does not take parameters`. Trying out a snippet in the empty package is a valid use case.

Answer (score 1):

You might wonder what `Option` you are referring to.

From `sbt console`, use `//print<tab>`:

```
scala> Option //print
   scala.Option // : Option.type
```

For better context:

```
package nooption

class Option(arg: String)  // some other option on class path
object Option

object Test {
  import scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = println {
    //Option(null)
    //ScalaClassLoader.originOfClass(classOf[Option])
    ScalaClassLoader.originOfClass(classOf[Option$])
  }
}
```

The class name for the companion object has a dollar at the end.

Your IDE might "go to definition."

If you started a REPL at the command line, class files in the current directory are on its class path. If you previously compiled an `Option` in the default or "empty" package, it will hide `scala.Option`.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that Frank asked.

Comment: @Tim As I said in the comments, it compiles and runs in 2.12.5 without problems. Therefore, it's not obvious to me that Frank *asked anything at all*. Voted to close as not reproducible.

Comment: @Tim This is an answer to "how do I overcome this?". Unfortunate name collisions are not uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this code does compile OK, but you really shouldn't use `null` in Scala unless you are interfacing with Java.

This is a better way of implementing your code:

```
val r = Try{ someString.split("/")(0) }.toOption
```

`Try` is widely used in Scala so this code is clear to anyone experienced with the language, so there is no need for a separate function.